# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php, arrays, countable

im getting this warning on my website "Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home4/geec/public_html/home/wp-content/plugins/industing-assistance/inc/elementor/style/services/style1.php on line 92

here is my line 92

echo substr($content, 0, ($spos = strpos($content, ' ', $lcount = count($content) > 65 ? $lcount : 65)) ? $spos : $lcount );

What exactly do I need to add or change on my php file?
Thanks

Comment: That single line of code, apart from not being complete, does not even contain a call to `count()`. You need to give us some _proper_ information here at least.

Comment: What do you want to do if $content is false or null, like it seems?

Comment: then, what should i put in content?

Comment: here is the complete line 

echo substr($content, 0, ($spos = strpos($content, ' ', $lcount = count($content) > 65 ? $lcount : 65)) ? $spos : $lcount );

Comment: might be off topic so i am writing it as comment it might be due to PHP version too. I had similar issue when I needed lower version of php

Comment: `count($content)` it seems `$content` is not an array or object, If it an object of a class, that class should implement `Countable` interface

Comment: would you help me on telling me what exact code I need to put in order to fix it? when you say implement countable interface

Comment: It hard to tell how to implement until you don't share what is `$content`. Share output of this `var_dump($content);`